# SharePoint Online Rest API Limit

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I am planning to create an application that will send out email to each member of a sharepoint group using JSOM and REST API but I am not sure what possible limit I can encounter doing it? I know that SharePoint will block you if you hit certain number of network transaction. I was wondering anybody know any limit I hit like for example calling rest api for a specific number of times in a certain time period will give you some kind of timeout.

Writing about it, I am thinking that doing it on Batch might be a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

SPO rate limit has not been exposed. To avoid getting blocked, please take a reference of below materials:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/handle-sharepoint-online-throttling-by-using-exponential-back-off